# ionic 3 android production build issue

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am building the app for production using ionic3. When I build ios, everything is fine. But I build the android with command

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

It have a error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.google.gms:google-services:11+.
 Versions that do not match:
     3.2.0
     3.1.2
     3.1.1
     3.1.0
     3.0.0
     + 42 more
 Required by:
     project :
```

My ionic info is:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0

System:

ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
Node       : v7.10.0
npm        : 5.5.1 
OS         : macOS Sierra

Environment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

backend : legacy
```

Did anyone faced before or know how to solve it? Thanks a lot

Comment: Usually it's due to some plugin. And did you try another cordova-android (6.4.0 or above) version?

Answer (score 0):

- Open SDK Manager and install current sdk tool and google-services.
- Set ANDROID_HOME path in system enviromental variables.
- Build and optimize your ionic code: 
  ionic cordova build android --prod --release --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --optimizejs